# XSLT transformation for name value pairs

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to format source XML to target format which has given below. But this is not working as expected.

Value of "**AttributeName**" should become element name in target xml and value of element "**AttributeValue**" should become the value. Source and target sample XMLS's are given below  How can I achieve this using XSLT?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResultSet4>
    <Record4>
        <FulfillmentID>49</FulfillmentID>
        <LineID>324</LineID>
        <OrderID>2109006</OrderID>
        <AttributeName>LAST_EXTRACT_NUMBER</AttributeName>
        <AttributeValue>test64565</AttributeValue>
    </Record4>
        <Record4>
        <FulfillmentID>49</FulfillmentID>
        <LineID>324</LineID>
        <AttributeName>LAST_EXTRACT_NUMBER</AttributeName>
        <AttributeValue>test64565</AttributeValue>
    </Record4>
</ResultSet4>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResultSet4>
    <Record4>
        <FulfillmentID>49</FulfillmentID>
        <LineID>324</LineID>
        <OrderID>2109006</OrderID>
        <Line bridged >test12 </Line bridged >
    </Record4>
    <Record4>
        <FulfillmentID>50</FulfillmentID>
        <LineID>324</LineID>
        <OrderID>2109006</OrderID>
        <LAST_EXTRACT_NUMBER>test64565</LAST_EXTRACT_NUMBER>
    </Record4>
</ResultSet4>
```

where tags

```
<AttributeName>LAST_EXTRACT_NUMBER</AttributeName> and                            
<AttributeValue>test64565</AttributeValue>
```

should be converted into one tag
        like:

`<Line bridged >test12 </Line bridged >`.

Comment: "*I've also included XSLT code.*" I don't see it.

Comment: <xsl:template match="Record4">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$(<xsl:value-of select ="local-name()"/>)!='AttributeName'">
               <xsl:element name="local-name()">
    <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:element name="{translate(AttributeName,' ','')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="AttributeValue"/>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Value of "AttributeName" should become element name in target xml and value of element "AttributeValue" should become the value.

Here's one way this could be done:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AttributeName">
    <xsl:element name="{.}">
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::AttributeValue"/>
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AttributeValue"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is different from the one shown in your question, but I believe that's more a flaw of the question than of the answer.

Note that this assumes `AttributeName` will always contain a valid XML element name.